# CAST & CONVERT from nvarchar to date simply won't work for column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I keep getting the error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

This works:

```
CONVERT(datetime, '20180718', 103)
```

This doesn't work:

```
CONVERT(datetime, (RIGHT([DATE],4)+SUBSTRING([DATE], 4,2)+LEFT([DATE], 2)), 103)
```

It's the exact same thing, why won't it work?

EDIT: The [DATE] nvarchar column has this format: 18/07/2018. So when I use the Right, Substring, and Left, I get 20180718

[This is the dates I'm using after concatenation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/666QS.png)

Answer (score 2):

That is not the exact same thing. Look at what your string is returning.

```
declare @Date varchar(10) = '18072018'

select RIGHT(@Date,4)+SUBSTRING(@Date, 4,2)+LEFT(@Date, 2)
```

Comment: I didn't notice that.  Even if all the data is good he is not using the correct substring positions.  Good eye.

Comment: fair enough, it's my fault because I made a mistake writing the question. Let me edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need to do concatenation, you can use `convert()` with style code `103` :

```
select convert(datetime, '18/07/2018', 103)
```

Style code `103` is actually for `dd/mm/yyyy` (British/French Standard) this is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles).

Comment: That was my first try. Using CONVERT(datetime, [DATE], 103) gives the error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. See the image on my post to see the date column.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  As Sean pointed out in his answer it might just be you are grabbing the wrong pieces of the strings.  If it still don't work see below:

It is not the same thing and that's the point.  The first is hard coded and a valid date.  The error is saying that at least one row of your data does not contain a valid date.  I would try to run counts by each date part (ie Right(Date,4)).  This will make it easier to find the values that are causing trouble.  Months should be 1 - 12, days should be 1-30,31, 28 or 29...

Comment: I thought that but I ran a distinct count. I only have 8 dates and they are correct... See the image I added.

Answer (score 0):

SQL error 241 occurs when a date and time value is being converted from a string representation to a DATETIME data type representation and SQL Server cannot perform the conversion due to an incorrectly formatted date/time value.
This may help you to get idea: 
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-241.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue - the query didn't return any NULL dates because it was using an inner join, but the NULLs existed. I thought the convert would only apply after the inner join.